# modify select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’m trying to modify this select statement

```
SELECT Month
      ,Day
      ,AvgLo 'Average Low' 
FROM dbo.Weather
```

to  produces that Average Low for only today’s date.  And then have it add the data to a new table called TodayWeather. How would I go about getting this done?

Comment: Use `Where` clause to filter the records with today's date. Then insert the filtered records into `TodayWeather` table. Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2016 Management Studio

Comment: IMHO you should create view for Today(s)Weather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW TodaysWeather
SELECT [Month]
      ,[Day]
      ,AvgLo 'Average Low' 
FROM dbo.Weather 
WHERE [Month] = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
AND [Day] = DAY(GETDATE())
```

This will always be up to date :)

Comment: Actually, if the table contains data over many years, this would return date from all the years the table contains...

Answer (score 0):

You can copy data from one table and insert into another like this:
for example your new table is TodayWeather and have column 'AvgLo '
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

i am doing this for single column,
 your table 'Weather' donot has date field, if you add date then query look like this

```
Insert into TodayWeather ( AvgLo ) SELECT AvgLo as 'Average Low'  FROM dbo.Weather where date = 'some date'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
INSERT INTO TodaysWeather
SELECT [Month], [Day], AVG(AvgLo) as [Average Low] 
FROM dbo.Weather 
WHERE [Month] = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND [Day] = DAY(GETDATE())
GROUP BY Month, Day
```